# Find vector direction when magnitude is known, but origin is unknown

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I have several vectors of which I know their magnitudes and their end positions on an X,Y plane. I need to find the direction of each vector. I realize this is probably a very simple question, but I can't recall the vector math needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All vectors originate from the same point which is also unknown.

Comment: What do you mean by "end positions" ? Do they all start at the origin?

Comment: @Jim I edited my question. Now I'm asking, "I drove 50 miles to Flint, MI and 90 miles to Detroit, where did I start?"

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) As it is now, it is hard to get exactly what you are asking. If you have simply one vector with an end point and a length, you have a circle of possible beginning points. If you have more information than that, we might be able to help if you help us understand the question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you do. Draw a circle around each end point the size of its magnitude. The location where all the rings intersect is your start location, from there you can probably figure out how to find the directions.

Mathematically, you could try making some simultaneous equations. If $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the i-th end points and $(x,y)$ is the starting point and $m_i$ is the i-th magnitude, then set up a system that looks like this:

$$(x_i-x)^2+(y_i-y)^2=m_i^2$$

Assuming you have more than two points AND assuming those points are not all co-linear, the starting location should be the only set of $(x,y)$ coordinates that satisfies every equation in the system.

Comment: A note: if this is experimental data, measurement errors will cause these circles to not line up perfectly.  In such a case, you will have to use more advanced techniques, such as doing a least squares regression to fit your data.

Comment: Note:  If you *know* that there is one common start, then  use only three vectors.   Three is enough to find the common starting point.  If you use more than three,  you might run into calculation issues, and you may do a lot more algebra than you need to.  Choose three endpoints that are "far away" from each other.

Comment: @Jim What concept is you equation derived from?

Comment: @CraigK. I guess the Pythagorean theorem is the base concept. The fundamental point is that the correct starting point is the only one that can mathematically result in all vectors having the correct magnitude. So you find the magnitude of each vector and solve the system for the common origin

Comment: @garyp And choose points that are not co-linear, obviously

Comment: @Jim After working for a little while I made a stupid assumption that three equations could be equal and thus I could find x and y. Obviously this is wrong because if this was correct all magnitudes would be equivalent. So how can I find what x and y are equal to with three equations of non-equivalency? Do I need to use a system of equations?

Comment: @CraigK. Yes, use a system of equations. Alternatively, you could try to guess the answer, but that's not the most mathematically sound approach